# Siddhi JOIN events ALSO after window is EXPIRED

Tags: stream, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

According to an [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/06/understanding-siddhi-powers-wso2-cep-2x/) from WSO2 website when you **JOIN** events from two streams then following happens:

> when an event from one stream reaches the In-Stream Join Processor, it is matched against all the available events of the other stream's Window Processor. When a match is found, those matched events are then sent to the Query Projector to create the output in-events; at the same time, the original event will be added to the Window Processor and it will remain there until it expires. Similarly, when an event expires from its Window Processor, it is matched against all the available events of the other stream's Window Processor; when a match is found, those matched events are sent to the Query Projector to create the output expired-events.

Basically, an event will be matched against other stream's window's events when it **arrives** and again will be looking for **new matches** when it's **expired** from its window. But this is not the behavior I'm noticing in a testing environment that I've setup. Here's my query:

```
FROM first_names#window.time(1 min) AS fst
UNIDIRECTIONAL JOIN last_names#window.time(2 min) AS lst
ON fst.identifier == lst.identifier
SELECT
  fst.identifier,
  fst.firstName,
  lst.lastName
INSERT INTO full_names
```

Then I publish the following events in the order laid out below to their respective streams:

```
{
  "lastName": "Colbert",
  "identifier": 1
}

{
  "firstName": "Stephen",
  "identifier": 1
}

{
  "lastName": "Carell",
  "identifier": 1
}
```

When the **second** event **arrives**, its counterpart already exists in the **other stream's** window so they match and the **joined** event is emitted right away as expected:

```
{
  "firstName": "Stephen",
  "lastName": "Colbert",
  "identifier": 1
}
```

Then the newly arrived event **also** gets stored in its stream **window** for **one minute**:

```
{
  "firstName": "Stephen",
  "identifier": 1
}
```

When the **one minute** is up and this event is being expired, a **new counterpart** for it exists in the other stream's window:

```
{
  "lastName": "Carell",
  "identifier": 1
}
```

So based on that article it should be matched with it and a new **joined** event sent as well looking like:

```
{
  "firstName": "Stephen",
  "lastName": "Carell",
  "identifier": 1
}
```

**BUT**, this event never arrives and the flow does not behave as explained in that article!!!

Any idea what might be causing this or if the article's claim is accurate and representative of the `WSO2 Siddhi` behavior? Because I did not see this in the official docs or other articles, so I'm a bit suspicious of this. Thanks in advance, I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour explained in the above article is accurate. The issue seems to be with your query. In your test query, you are using `INSERT INTO full_names`, so only **current events** will get emitted to the stream. However, events that get joined with an **expired event** will get emitted to the stream as **expired events**. So if you want to get those **expired events**, you have to mention it specifically using its output event category (i.e `INSERT EXPIRED EVENTS INTO full_names` or `INSERT ALL EVENTS INTO full_names`). Please refer to the following [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Outputeventcategories) to get to know more about output event categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this brings up a few trade offs and follow up concerns. Using `ALL` will result in duplicate output. `msg1` arrives from `S1` and if there's a match in `S2`'s window like `msg2`, it'll match and emit the **joined** event. Then when it expires, if `msg2` is still in the `S2`'s window, it'll match **again** and emit the **joined** event again. And if **not**, it'll emit the **non-matched** version of `msg1` as well even though it already found a match for it upon its arrival. Tweaking with `UNIDIRECTINOAL` and `window size`, it's possible to minimize this duplication.

Comment: But not our desired behavior! I need every event from `S1`; if there is a match for it in `S2`, the **joined** event would suffice and if there is no match, then just emit the event as is. But with `UNIDIRECTIONAL LEFT OUTER JOIN`, **single** event from `S1` will always result to **two** output events. One upon arrival and one after expiration. It can be `non-matched & matched`, `matched & non-matched`, `non-matched & non-matched` and `matched & matched`! I guess with `EXPIRED EVENTS` this behavior is achievable but it damages the real-time nature of our stream processing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is accepting this **duplication** at this level and trying to de-dup in the **downstream**! Any thoughts?